# AngularJS Calendar's years dropdown disappears in tablet but not in pc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, tablet

I have an SPA application that was developed in AngularJS.
In one of the pages I have an AngularJS input date field.
When I am opening the calendar's years dropdown on pc it works ok, but when i open it in tablet, the years seems to disappear when I scroll back down.

Does anyone knows what can be the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I AM NOT ALLOWED TO ADD CODE AT THIS POINT. PLEASE ADVICE IN GENERAL.